# Setup up MWAA XCom backend to be S3

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I know that XCom backend can be changed when using default Apache Airflow in Linux, ubuntu, docker, etc. However, I'm looking particularly if it is possible with MWAA.

Is it possible to setup Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) to change XCom Backend to be using S3? If is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: I can use in local  my custom backend ,but in MWAA show error  "INCORRECT_CONFIGURATION" , did you manage to do it?